# Navigation terminated

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my view controller if I navigate through the Root view controller it works okay through this code,

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But when i try to custom navigation to viewcontroller through below code,

```
ViewController2 *vc = [[[ViewController2 alloc] init]];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

by this my application is crashed and show me the Below error:

```
terminate called throwing an exception.
```

Help me to shortout it.

Comment: IS there something else in this error ? Maybe method name ?

Comment: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <View2: 0x898cb20>.
This error is seen at console

Answer (score 0):

You can only use that method to pop to a vc already in the array of view controllers.

EDIT: as developer new to iOS, you need to spend the time to read (and re-read) the UINavigation Controller class description, and the two or three Apple Guides on using UIViewController and the catalog of various view controller. Yes, its a lot of stuff to read and comprehend - but then, all of us doing iOS work now have done it too. There is no magic way to get your app to work. Your use of popToViewController demonstrates to the community that you have not done the above, as you would not have posted the question if you'd read the documents.

People who try to help others here on SO are much more likely to do so if it appears you have made an honest effort to get something to work, but are stymied in some way where an experienced person can provide insight.

Comment: Sir I am new in ios.can you answer it in detail sir?

Answer (score 0):

uinavigation just like a box , you can push anyVC in this box , but when you want to out ,you just popToRootVC .. you can't push VC that it outside in this box .